# Piecewise function inside Integrate - Wrong result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise, education

I tried to evaluate the following integral:

```
Integrate[0, {x, -Infinity, 0}] + Integrate[1/x, {x, 0, 1}] + 
 Integrate[0, {x, 1, +Infinity}]
(*Out: integral 1/x does not converge on {0,1} *)
```

The above result is correct.
There is a problem when I define the piecewise function:

```
f2[t_] := Piecewise[{{0, t < 0},
   {1/t, 0 <= t <= 1},
   {0, t > 1}}]
Integrate[f2[t], {t, -Infinity, +Infinity}]
```

In this case Mathematica does not evaluate the integral; I expect the same output as before. Why and how can I overcome this situation?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Indeed, even the simpler `Integrate[Piecewise[{{1/t, 0 <= t <= 1}}, 0], {t, -∞, ∞}]` is left unevaluated. So the result is not so much "wrong" as it is a case of "*Mathematica* doesn't know what to do". (Incidentally, re-expressing the integral as `Integrate[UnitStep[1 - t] UnitStep[t]/t, {t, -∞, ∞}]` is also *no bueno*.)